# Google Sheets regexextract multiple text strings from a cell

Tags: regex, google-sheets

I am trying to extract the hashtag info from a twitter data cell in google sheets.

We can call this Cell A1:

```
[{"text":"QOTD","indices":[13,18]},{"text":"CSEC4CG","indices":[87,95]},{"text":"myCSEC","indices":[96,103]},{"text":"Connecticut","indices":[104,116]},{"text":"GiveBack","indices":[117,126]},{"text":"COVID19","indices":[127,135]}]
```

In a perfect situation I would be able to produce this in another cell extracted from A1:

```
#QOTD #CSEC4CG #myCSEC #Connecticut #Giveback #COVID19
```

I am lost how to do it using REGEXTRACT.  I assume this is the best method, but any that gets the job done is good.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to achieve the following conversion using the built-in functions in Google Spreadsheet.

- From

  ```
      [{"text":"QOTD","indices":[13,18]},{"text":"CSEC4CG","indices":[87,95]},{"text":"myCSEC","indices":[96,103]},{"text":"Connecticut","indices":[104,116]},{"text":"GiveBack","indices":[117,126]},{"text":"COVID19","indices":[127,135]}]
  ```
- To

  ```
      #QOTD #CSEC4CG #myCSEC #Connecticut #Giveback #COVID19
  ```

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

#### Sample formula:

```
=TRIM(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"\[|\]|,",""),"{""text"":""(.+?)""""indices"":.+?}"," #$1"))
```

- In this case, it supposes that the input value is put in the cell "A1".
- The flow is as follows.

  1. Replace `\[|\]|,` with `""` using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  2. Replace `{""text"":""(.+?)""""indices"":.+?}` with `" #$1"` using `REGEXREPLACE`.
  3. The top space is removed with `TRIM`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### References:

- [REGEXREPLACE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245)
- [TRIM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094140)

Comment: Really great answer.  Exactly what I needed and taught me how to deal with quotes in regexreplace.  Thank you!